# Share VPC networks with Google Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking, gke-networking

I have been looking for any answer to this question for a couple of days now.  The image shows what I am trying to do.  Basically I want to build a container engine cluster in a service project but use a network from a shared vpc in a host project.  This works with compute engine just fine and since container engine leverages compute engine I can't see what it wouldn't work but the options are not there to configure it.

The ultimate goal is to use this in a hybrid cloud scenario and for each container project we would rather leverage a single vpn tunnel instead of building new ones for every project.  That simply doesn't scale.

[Google Cloud Container engine networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axekD.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** This is now officially supported. See [Adam MacDonald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50482848/747032).

---

I have been looking to implement the same set-up, But it looks like GKE in service projects using a shared VPC is currently not supported:

> Shared VPC limitations
>
> - Quota of 100 shared VPC host projects per Cloud Organization.
> - Quota of 100 service projects attached to any given shared VPC host project.
> - External load balancing is not supported across projects. This means that the frontend of a load balancer must exist in the same project as the backends, but the backend instances in service projects can be created in the shared VPC network of the host project.
> - **GKE clusters in a service project associated with an shared VPC network are not supported.**
> - GAE Flexible in a service project associated with an shared VPC network is not supported.
> - Deployment manager is limited to manage resources within a single project.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shared-vpc/provisioning-shared-vpc#shared_vpc_limitations

Comment: Yes, you are right, currently this is not supported but I know that Google has a feature request opened to use shared VPC network with GKE [link](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/63522931)

Answer (score 2):

Shared VPC is now supported for Google Kubernetes engine. See https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Introducing-Shared-VPC-for-Google-Kubernetes-Engine.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that natively now!
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc